# on change selects not working well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I`m trying to make a simple select which generate the next select box...
but I cant seem to make it work

so, as you can see I'm making divs that have ID and parent, when I'm clicking on the first select the value generate the next select box with the divs and the parent value.

this is the jQuery, but for some reason I cant understand why its not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  var t = '#ss' + i;
  $(t).change(function() {
    i++;
    t = '#ss' + i;
    var pick = $(this).val();
    $('#picks div').each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr('parent') == pick) {
        $('#ss' + i).append('<option value=' + $(this).text() + ' >' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
      }
      $('#ss' + i).removeAttr('disabled');
    })
    console.log(t);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='picks'>
  <div id='29' parent='26'>Pick1</div>
  <div id='30' parent='29'>Pick11</div>
  <div id='31' parent='26'>Pick</div>
</div>

<select id="ss1">
        <option >First pick</option>
        <option value="26">Angri</option>
        <option value="27">lands</option>
        <option value="28">tree</option>
    </select>
<select id="ss2" disabled>
        <option >Secound Pick</option>
    </select>
<select id="ss3" disabled>
        <option>Third Pick</option>
    </select>
```

Here is a jsfiddle [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/153178/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were shooting for? https://jsfiddle.net/6c5t8ort/

A couple things,

`var t = '#ss' + i;
  $(t).change(function() {`

This only adds the `change` event to the first dropdown. If you give jQuery a selector (a class) if will add the event to all the elements though. Also the way you had your `i` variable set up means it would increment on every change.

Answer (score 0):

The code below only attaches a change listener to the first ss `ss1` so the change function is never called when you change `ss2`.

```
  var i = 1;
  var t = '#ss' + i;
  $(t).change(function() {
```

You can fix this by adding a class on each select and using `$(".myClass").change(function() {`

or you can just attach the listener to all selects `$("select").change(function() {`

Also the value for the `option` tag does not include a "parent" number. In this case it would be `Pick`, `Pick1`, or `Pick11`.

```
$('#ss' + i).append('<option value=' + $(this).text() + ' >' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
```